# How to convert JSON to Java object

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using Jackson ObjectMapper
I have below JSON and Java Class. I am getting exception. Could someone tell me whats wrong with my Java class

JSON:

```
{"name":
    [
        {
            "field1":"value1",
            "field2":"value2"
        },
        {
            "field1":"value1",
            "field2":"value2"
        },
        {
            "field1":"value1",
            "field2":"value2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Java Class:
AnyJsonObject.java:

```
public class AnyJsonObject {
    private List<Name> name;

    public List<Name> getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(List<Name> name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Name.java:

```
public class Name {

    @JsonProperty("field1")
    public String fieldOne;

    public String field2;

}
```

Code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.readValue(json, AnyJsonObject.class);
```

I get java.lang.Exception: Error occurred when de-serializing json

Comment: Remove `requestHostName`, or add it into the JSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `AnyJsonObject class` you have following lines:

```
private List<Name> name;

// wrong place here
public Name getName() {
    return name;
}
```

You are returning `List<Name>` type but method signature is `public Name getName()`. You should fix return type:

```
public List<Name> getName() {
    return name;
}
```

**Edit:**

I have modified your source code and used `Jackson 2` lib. Here is my implementation of this task:

Here is `class Name`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Name {

    @JsonProperty("field1")
    public String fieldOne;

    @JsonIgnore
    public String field2; // this field will be ignored

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "field1: " + fieldOne + ", field2: " + field2;
    }
}
```

Here is `AnyJsonObject class`:

```
import java.util.List;

public class AnyJsonObject {
    private List<Name> name;

    public List<Name> getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(List<Name> name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Name n : name) sb.append(n.toString());

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

And here is `Test class`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "{\"name\":\n" +
                "    [\n" +
                "        {\n" +
                "            \"field1\":\"value1\",\n" +
                "            \"field2\":\"value2\"\n" +
                "        },\n" +
                "        {\n" +
                "            \"field1\":\"value1\",\n" +
                "            \"field2\":\"value2\"\n" +
                "        },\n" +
                "        {\n" +
                "            \"field1\":\"value1\",\n" +
                "            \"field2\":\"value2\"\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "    ]\n" +
                "}";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {
            AnyJsonObject any = mapper.readValue(json, AnyJsonObject.class);
            System.out.println(any);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

> **Output of execution:**
>
> field1: value1, field2: value2field1: value1, field2: value2field1: value1, field2: value2

Comment: Thanks. If my json string has 10 fields and I only want to use 5 fields in my Java bean then it is not working. Should I include all the fields in my Java bean even if I am not going to use those fields?

Comment: add @JsonIgnore annotation to ignore fields

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative suggest using gson (https://github.com/google/gson)
It also helps read json to Java object, like:

```
public List<Class_to_create_json_of> readJsonToObject(String jsonContent) {

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    try {
         json = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(jsonContent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
         handleException(e);
    }
    return gson.fromJson(json.toString(),
                new TypeToken<List<Class_to_create_json_of>>() {}.getType());
}
```

Class_to_create_json_of is the class that represents your Json - String fields for string values, boolean for boolean, etc....
For example:

```
{
  "some_key" : "some_velue",
  "some_other_key" : 1,
  "some_third_key" : true
}

public class jsonContent {
   private String some_key;
   private int some_other_key;
   privtae boolean some_third_key;

   public setSome_key(String some_key) {
       this.some_key = some_key;
   }
   public setSome_other_key(int some_other_key) {
      this.some_other_key = some_other_key;
   }
   public setSome_third_key(boolean some_third_key) {
      this.some_third_key = some_third_key;
   }

   public getSome_key() {
       return some_key;
   }
   public getSome_other_key(i) {
      return some_other_key;
   }
   public getSome_third_key() {
      return some_third_key;
   }
}
```

Comment: what is the structure of Class_to_create_json_of

Comment: I've updated the answer with the Class_to_create_json_of

Answer (score 0):

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType;import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode;public static  T jsonToPojo(String jsonData, Class beanType) { try { T t = MAPPER.readValue(jsonData, beanType);return t;} catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}return null;}